# Setting xkbmap in Wayland

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard, wayland, sway, capslock

I am using Sway & Wayland on Arch with a fresh install. Everything is going well, besides one problem which I usually have, however this time I cannot solve it.

On every Linux distro I have tried, <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> enables when you press, but disables when you release on the second press. As somebody who types capital letters with <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> (and I have been for the last 14 years), this is really difficult as it produces text like the following:

```
HEllo there, my name is ALfie
```

Some of you may be included to say "just type with <kbd>Shift</kbd>", but instead I hope I can find a way to map my <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key.

Historically [this](https://github.com/hexvalid/Linux-CapsLock-Delay-Fixer/issues/12) method has worked for fixing the issue. However, as I am not using X, I am having issues getting this to work.

When running the first command, a warning is given about my display:

```
[aalfie@aalfie Documents]$ xkbcomp -xkb $DISPLAY keyboardmap
Warning:          Could not load keyboard geometry for :0
                  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
                  Resulting keymap file will not describe geometry
```

And then proceeding to replace the mapping and set the map, the output appears to work as nomral:

```
aalfie@aalfie Documents]$ xkbcomp keyboardmap $DISPLAY
No symbols defined for <AB11> (keycode 97)
No symbols defined for <JPCM> (keycode 103)
No symbols defined for <I120> (keycode 120)
No symbols defined for <AE13> (keycode 132)
No symbols defined for <I149> (keycode 149)
No symbols defined for <I154> (keycode 154)
No symbols defined for <I168> (keycode 168)
No symbols defined for <I178> (keycode 178)
No symbols defined for <I183> (keycode 183)
No symbols defined for <I184> (keycode 184)
No symbols defined for <FK19> (keycode 197)
No symbols defined for <FK24> (keycode 202)
No symbols defined for <I217> (keycode 217)
No symbols defined for <I219> (keycode 219)
No symbols defined for <I222> (keycode 222)
No symbols defined for <I230> (keycode 230)
No symbols defined for <I248> (keycode 248)
```

However, no changes are actually made to the keyboard mapping.

(I already have XWayland).

Comment: Not a proper answer, but I got it fixed using the following:

https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/qlxh4p/comment/hj7s0td/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

https://www.reddit.com/r/swaywm/comments/i2uurb/remapping_key_using_xkb/

Put the modifier in the first in the places suggested by the second. Works on Arch Linux using Sway.

Comment: Research further tells me that this is not a Wayland issue but a Sway shortcoming / difficulty as the compositor handles input, not Wayland itself (unlike X)